# How to disable method inlining in proguard?

Tags: proguard, android-4.4-kitkat, illegalaccessexception

My app is crashing with this error on Android 4.4 only

Fatal Exception: nTa: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class dUa$a[] from class patient.healofy.vivoiz.com.healofy.userprofile.contactsync.ContactSyncManager
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError + 367(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run + 69(ScheduledRunnable.java:69)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call + 57(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run + 237(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201 + 152(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run + 265(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1112(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 587(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 841(Thread.java:841)

I found that it is happening due to ProGuard method inlining.

I want to disable these two:

**method/inlining/short**
Inlines short methods.
**method/inlining/unique**
Inlines methods that are only called once.

I have not specifically enabled them.

For detailed answer:
https://medium.com/@ericluapp/a-journey-of-an-illegalaccesserror-issue-2c29b6ea968d

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable method inlining completely you can add this to your configuration

`-optimizations !method/inlining/*`