# Exception in minifying rxjava3 with R8

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to build my project with release variant and `minifyingEnabled = true` and I'm facing this exception in all time :

build debug APK is a success but build releaseApk is fail

please help me, I can't find the problem

```
FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
Stack trace:
com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
    ...
Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.U0.a(:14)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.U0.a(:9)
        at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.a0.a(:49)
        at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(:160)
        ...
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:472)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task.doTaskAction(R8Task.kt:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)]
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.T.a(:42)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.T.a(:33)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.p.a(:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.w.a(:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.w.a(:82)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(:520)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(:417)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.b(:53)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Try this [How to disable method inlining in proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778424/how-to-disable-method-inlining-in-proguard)

Comment: @Nicolas I just tried that right now but that did not work